# Is there such a thing as 'Korean Microsoft Windows 10' or is it just regular Windows preconfigured to Korean language, fonts etc?

Tags: windows, .net-framework, international, korean, winforms

I have a Korean client who has a display issue using our software, and I'm having no success reproducing his issue on my PC, even after changing multiple settings to make my PC as Korean as possible.

Just wondering if the problem is that he bought his copy of Windows 10 in Korea and I did not.

Is it worth persevering with attempting to make my PC more 'Korean', and maybe does anyone have a definitive list of everything needed to change a Windows install to be exactly like a (in this case Korean) PC?

Or is it possible that there is simply some fundamental difference between my Windows and my client's, owing to the fact that he bought "Korean Windows"?

My guess and hope is that buying Windows 10 in Korea gives you just the same version as in any other country, just preconfigured for Korean, but it would be good to have this confirmed.

EDIT: Have now fixed this programmatically, please see my answer.

Comment: I have exactly this issue in 2023 with a Windows forms app.  It's even a Korean customer in my case, too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are editions of Windows without the Media components, a European one known as the N Edition & a Korean one known as the KN Edition.

If your client's issue is media-related, this could well be the cause.
It is 'fixable' insomuch as the components can be added separately, from Microsoft - [Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231).

More information at MS KB : [Media feature pack for Windows 10 N and Windows 10 KN editions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3099229)

From Supersite: [What are the Windows 10 N and KN Editions?](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/what-are-windows-10-n-and-kn-editions)

> Due to a ruling for anti-competitive practices by the European
>   Commission in 2004, Microsoft has been forced to maintain special
>   editions for its Windows operating systems. Labeled "N" for Europe and
>   "KN" for Korea, these editions include all the base features of the
>   operating system but without Windows Media Player and related
>   technologies pre-installed. For the Windows 10 editions, this includes
>   Windows Media Player, Music, Video, Voice Recorder and Skype.
>
> If you reside in and purchase a PC in a country required to use the N
>   and KN editions, you receive a computer without media technologies.
>   This can cause some headaches, particularly when using apps and
>   visiting web sites that have been coded to utilize the built-in
>   Windows media capabilities. For a full list of excluded features,
>   check out Media feature pack for Windows 10 N and Windows 10 KN
>   editions on the Microsoft support site.
>
> The ruling was about consumer choice. However, if you choose to, you
>   can still install Windows Media Player and related apps anytime for
>   free by downloading and installing a special Media Feature Pack.
>
> You can find the download for Windows 10 here: [Media Feature Pack for
>   N and KN versions of Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231)

Answer (score 2):

The font sizing in the Korean Windows 10 is different than the font size in the English version.  We have software which uses winforms and the forms created are different between the two versions.  I had both systems up running side by side.

Comment: Upvoted, as this was the core of my problem. See also my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Going to post my own answer to this even though I already accepted another answer, in order to maybe help others.

I discovered that, as pointed out by user6759519, the default font and font size used by WinForms applications can be different depending on the country or region Windows was installed.

For example, as I found out, the default font used by WinForms applications running on UK/US Windows is 'Microsoft Sans Serif 9pt', whereas on Korean Windows it is 'Gulim 9pt'.

This resulted in numerous panels having incorrect dimensions resulting in clipping, and various places where text did not fit in controls properly.

The solution was to programmatically override this by setting the default font back to Sans Serif in the constructor of the top-level panel in our application, just after the call to InitializeComponent, for example:

```
Font = new Font(
    familyName: "Microsoft Sans Serif", 
    emSize: 9f, 
    style: FontStyle.Regular,
    unit: GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

This setting automatically cascades down to all child panels and controls as far as I an tell, and pretty much everything now looks correct (I've also confirmed this in the Japanese edition of Windows 10).

Note: There may still be issues on some child panels even after overriding the default font, depending on the setting of some or all of the following in the child panel designer code:

```
AutoScaleMode
AutoScaleDimensions
AutoSize
```

Note: One more thing (after re-reading my question), I was never able to reproduce our Korean customer's issue by making my UK installation of Windows 'more Korean' (i.e. no setting I found changes the default font picked by WinForms) - instead I had to download Korean Windows from MSDN, and install it in VmWare. In order to use it without learning Korean(!), I was then able to change the default language into English, by navigating the relevant settings screens side by side with another PC running UK Windows - tricky but it is possible! I was then able to install Visual Studio and solve my issue programmatically as explained above).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful!  Thank you for taking the time to write this up; it will help me enormously in fixing what sounds like an almost identical issue.

Answer (score -1):

There are no language specific versions of windows 10.

Additional languages can be installed, but other than that, the only significant differences to Windows versions are:

Windows 10 basic, Windows 10 with bing (sort of basic version), windows 10 pro and windows 10 enterprise. It is vital to ensure that you match these verions, especially if it is regarding basic or Windows 10 with bing, as they may be missing vital functions.

So to answer your question: No, the windows being korean has nothing to do with your problem if you configured yours properly.

Comment: what about the N & KN editions?

Comment: "There are no language specific versions of windows 10." What about Single Language version of Home?